# TextField and DatePicker are providing null values

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, null, textfield

I'm trying to make a todoApp and in my Add Screen there are a textfield for the title of the task and a DatePicker for the date of the task. I think everything is ok in the code cause there isnt any errors but when I click on the Add button, it creates a TaskTile with empty title and empty date. I debugged the code and it seems that the value that I provide in the Provider with the Add Button are empty. It's like what I type is deleted and what i choose in the datepicker is removed. Here's the code of my AddScreen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'task_data.dart';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String newTaskTitle;
DateTime _chosenDateTime;
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formatedDate;

void _showDatePicker(ctx) {
  
  showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) => Container(
            height: 500,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                      onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                        // setState(() {
                        //   _chosenDateTime = val;
                        // });
                        _chosenDateTime = val;
                        formatedDate = dateFormat.format(_chosenDateTime);
                        // print('this is the selected date $formatedDate');
                        // print(_chosenDateTime);
                      }),
                ),

                // Close the modal
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(ctx).pop(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ));
}

return Container(
  color: Color(0xff000014),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(0xFF282D3A),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Add Task',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.purple.shade400,
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          autofocus: true,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          onChanged: (newText) {
            newTaskTitle = newText;
          },
        ),
        
        Container(
          child: CupertinoButton(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.zero,
            child: Text('Select a date'),
            onPressed: () => _showDatePicker(context),
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            'Add',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.purple.shade400,
          onPressed: () {
            //print('newtasktile is $newTaskTitle et formateddate is $formatedDate');// here the two //values are null when printed
            Provider.of<TaskData>(context,listen: false )
                .addTask(newTaskTitle, formatedDate);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

If you have any suggestions please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your provider and listview class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to conveniently use the value of `TextField`, you should use `TextEditingController`. To get the value after selecting a datetime, you can return a value from the `Dialog` method, then send that value to `Stream`

Working code (I'm creating a simple UI with simple `StreamController` to demonstrate):

```dart
// TaskData class
class TaskData {
  final StreamController _controller =
      StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get taskStream => _controller.stream;

  addTask(String title, String date) {
    _controller.add({'title': title, 'date': date});
  }
}

// AddTask screen
class AddTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTaskScreenState createState() => _AddTaskScreenState();
}

class _AddTaskScreenState extends State<AddTaskScreen> {
  final _textController = TextEditingController();
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String chosenDate;
  
  Future<String> _showDatePicker(ctx) async {
      var formatedDate = DateTime.now();
      return showCupertinoModalPopup(
          context: ctx,
          builder: (_) => Container(
                height: 500,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 400,
                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                          initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                          onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
                            formatedDate = val;
                          }),
                    ),

                    // Close the modal
                    CupertinoButton(
                      child: Text('OK'),

                      // Return the formatted date here
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(ctx)
                          .pop(dateFormat.format(formatedDate)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          );
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(

          // ... other lines

          child: Column(
              
              // ... other lines

              TextField(
                // Use the _textController here
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                autofocus: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Container(
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.zero,
                  child: Text('Select a date'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Wait for the return value
                    chosenDate = await _showDatePicker(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.purple.shade400,
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                      .addTask(_textController.text, chosenDate);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Main UI Screen
class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen());
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Text('Add Task')),
              Container(
                  child: StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                initialData: {},
                stream: Provider.of<TaskData>(context).taskStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          '${snapshot.data['title']} | ${snapshot.data['date']}'),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: first, thank you very much for your response, it was very helpul. But I still can't make my adding task feature work well. I can't add code in a comment so here's my github repo where the entire project is : https://github.com/elios-cama/TodoListv2.git  . I want that when I click on add button on the AddScreen, it add a tile in a similar thing as a listview with a checkbox, the title and the date in my TaskList widget but I don't know how to do it with the stream and snapchots. Feel free to give some advice if you have time. Thanks! @Bach

Comment: @elios_cama In line 161 of AddTaskScreen.dart, you should use addTask1() instead of addTask(). It will work as expected! Btw can you choose this answer to be the Accepted answer, I'd be very appreciated!

Comment: ok yeah thanks it works now i'll try to put the snapchots into a listview